# What is a good icon for "notifications" tab?

Tags: icons, notification, tab-bar

We're trying to fit a nice notifications tab icon for our app. However, we couldn't find a global icon to define notifications. Facebook uses a globe (we can't use that, as we use globe to "discover/explore" tab in our app). Instagram uses a heart inside a chat bubble, but I don't think it represents "notifications" globally, it's more of a "like notifications". Twitter uses a bell, which, we think, is very ugly and doesn't fit the look and feel of our app. We've also seen exclamation marks inside triangles, but they represent more of a warning/error instead of notifications. We're looking for a good candidate for notifications icon. Is there a good one that everyone uses, or does it have the same fate with "share" icon in UX community?

Comment: See [How do you create or select an icon for a feature?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14571/how-do-you-create-or-select-an-icon-for-a-feature)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack exchange uses an "inbox" that changes to a # when you have notices. G+ uses a circle w/ a bell, which changes to a circle w/ a #. Another possibility would be a mail icon (or mailbox). Personally I kind of like the idea of a circle with a 0 in it, or whatever # of notices they have.

Comment: thanks, we'll be experimenting with a few of them and pick the best, then.

Comment: In an answer to a question specifically about compact, readily recognizable icons/images, is it wise to use a pound sign as shorthand for "number"?  The first time I read your answer I thought -- "I don't remember seeing a '#' on my SE inbox, what are they talking about?"

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it depends on what these notifications are.

If it's about a social network, an inbox (envelope) or chat bubble icon makes sense, as most of the notifications will be about other users messaging them.

On the other hand, if it's a service provider where most notifications will be automated processes telling you that an update finished or your server burnt down and your data is lost, it may be better to use a "I" (information) icon, or a warning triangle.

Comment: I want a server that can inform me when it has burnt down. ERROR 511: Server on Fire!

Comment: @aslum wouldn't the error code for that be 911?

Comment: Nah, That's be if the server broke into your house... or maybe the other way around. I'm not really familiar w/ any Server Error codes higher than the 500s. d:

Comment: @aslum back in the days, there [actually was](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp0_on_fire) a similar message about printers.

Comment: It's a social network, inbox envelope seems to be a good idea.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu chat bubble may be better. Envelopes are more for conventional e-mail like Gmail or webmail clients.

Comment: I'll try both and see which goes better. The problem is, we currently don't have chat/DM functionality (and may have in future), and chat bubble may create confusion in that sense.